# Как сделать ListBox многострочным?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Использую WinForms.

В неком элементе ListBox есть данные, это обычная строка, но встречаются случаи, когда строчка выходит за пределы элемента и часть строки соответственно не видно.

Можно ли ограничить рамки, чтобы строка переносилась или что-то в этом роде? Скажем например если я распарсю строку на 4 элемента и разделю, скажем первых 2 элемента на одной строке, вторые 2 на второй. Директива `System.Windows.Forms` присутствует

[image: Внимание на предпоследнюю строчку, видно, что строка не входит в размер листбокса]

[image: Если растянуть окно, то видно насколько она длинная]

Само окно в приложении я не смогу растягивать, т.к. оно будет использоваться на сканере, все размеры там уже догогнаны, можно ли разделить как-то строчку эту используя нижнее подчеркивание как разделитель?

UPD: Решение которое было предложено в комментариях к вопросу не подходит, т.к. используется `.NET Compact Framework` для `Windows Mobile device.`, который в свою очередь не поддерживает свойства по типу `DrawItem` и `DrawMode` Есть ли решение для моей задачи?

Comment: Это называется `Wrapping Text`, вот например первая ссылка [гугла](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17613613/winforms-dotnet-listbox-items-to-word-wrap-if-content-string-width-is-bigger-tha).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ почему-то не распознает ключевые слова типо `DrawMode`, `MeasureItem`, `DrawItem` ну и соответсвенно `ItemHeight`, `Graphics`, `DrawBackground`, не подскажете какую директиву я упустил?

Comment: И как вы пишете? Просто скопировали что-ли?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ конечно скопировал, но поменял имя ListBox на своё `this.lvValues.DrawMode`
примерно вот так, это что касается дизайнера, соответственно и все остальное также

Comment: Ну, я без понятия что у вас там, у меня пустой проект, просто скопировал все с того ответа, заменил имя и получил [это](https://pastebin.com/aGhWYEqt). Сама программа успешно отработала и выдала мне [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aipZ6.png). Как видите, все работает. Если у вас не работает, то я не знаю, может у вас ListBox нестандартный и он не имеет этих событий и свойств. Это уже ищите сами)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ ну по факту я сделал также, только мой `ListBox`  выдает следующее

`does not contain a definition for 'DrawItem'`, и так далее для всех параметров которые я добавил

Comment: @Sosiska, точно WinForms? Потому что это в WPF у `ListBox` нет таких свойств/событий.

Comment: @t3f, да это точно винформс, толстая приложуха

Comment: @Sosiska, вот с этого: "`используется .NET Compact Framework`" нужно было начинать. Похоже что в .NET Compact есть только один путь - это сделать свой собственный ListBox, где самостоятельно реализовать всё что нужно. По крайней мере, так написано здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms229679%28v%3dvs.100%29